# How to undo the effects of a 'tc qdisc change' command?

Tags: linux, networking, tc

I am playing with the **netem** examples from here https://wiki.linuxfoundation.org/networking/netem and I have learned that I can undo the effect of a **tc qdisc add** command with a similar **tc qdisc del** command. But how can I undo the effects of a **tc qdisc change** command?

Comment: `tc qsisc del` doesn't actually "undo" anything, it simply deletes a rule. So if you cange a rule with `tc qdisc change` you can change it back again to the old value.

Comment: @MrShunz this requires a way to see the value before I change it, how do I display it?